# How to use repeater databound on ASP net for bootstrap carrousel slides

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2013

Im geting items from sharepoint 2013 and call them through repeater.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater_slideshow" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
           <div class="<%# Container.ItemIndex == 0 ? "item active" : "item" %> row hidden-xs col-sm-12 slideshowItem">
                 <div class="wrapGallery col-sm-4">
                       <img class="img-responsive slideimage" src="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Image") %>">
                       <div class="imgGalleryDescription">
                           <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "HTMLField") %>
                       </div>
                 </div>
           </div>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

from codebehind I just get the list and I use the datasource and databind method on repeater:

```
Collection<HighLights> l = ContentHelper.ExecuteQuery<HighLights>(Portal.Lists.Highlight, ServerRelativeURL);                
this.repeater_slideshow.DataSource = l;
this.repeater_slideshow.DataBind();
```

Having 3 ITEMS on my list, in the output , the slideshow only shows 1 item per slide insdead of all of 3 items...after some google search I found out that I have to use repeater item databound inside the repeater from the code above that I've showed you(repeater inside repeater)...the problem is that I have no clue how to work with repeater itemdatabound... and what to do to make the 3 items from the list appear on each slide , instead of showing only 1 item!!!
Any help is appreciated

PS: sorry if this is repost.

EDIT:
Found the solution :-)

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater"runat="server"OnItemDataBound="repeater_ItemDataBound">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="<%# Container.ItemIndex == 0 ? "item active" : "item" %> row col-sm-12 slideshowItem">
                            <asp:Repeater ID="repeater_slideshow" runat="server">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <div class="wrapGallery">
                                            <img class="img-responsive slideimage" src="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Image") %>">
                                            <div class="imgGalleryDescription">
                                                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "HTMLField") %>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

codebehind:

if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {

```
            Collection<HighLights> d = ContentHelper.ExecuteQuery<HighLights>(Portal.Lists.Highlight, ServerRelativeURL);
              if (d != null && d.Count > 0)
            {
                this.Visible = true;

                int num1 = d.Count;
                int num2 = 3;
                decimal result = Convert.ToDecimal(num1) / Convert.ToDecimal(num2);

                int quociente = (int)Math.Ceiling(result);

                List<int> list = new List<int>(); ;

                for (int i = 1; i <= quociente; i++)
                {
                    list.Add(i);
                }
                this.repeater.DataSource = list;
                this.repeater.DataBind();

            }
```

the code above is inside page_load;

after pageload:

```
  protected void repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {

            Collection<HighLights> l = ContentHelper.ExecuteQuery<HighLights>(Portal.Lists.Highlight, ServerRelativeURL);
            Repeater rpt = e.Item.FindControl("repeater_slideshow") as Repeater;

            int aux = (int)e.Item.DataItem * 3;

            if (aux <= 3)
            {
                rpt.DataSource = l.Take(3);
            }

            else
            {
                rpt.DataSource = l.Skip(aux - 3).Take(3);
            }

            rpt.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your slideshow occurring once because in image tag you have passed same image `src="/img_slide_institucional_01.png"` for all three items. This need to be dynamic.

Comment: ok so just did that and yet it uses 1 item per slide instead of 3...`code` <img class="img-responsive slideimage" src="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Image") %>"> `code`

Answer (score 0):

I once did the same thing in SharePoint 2010, I actually used [bxslider](http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified), and it's the slider that lets you define the number of elements per slide (so no need for a repeater inside repeater).

Here's my repeater code :

```
<div id="slider" class="slider1">
       <asp:Repeater ID="repeater_slideshow" runat="server">
              <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="slide">
                           // 1 item here
                   </div>
             </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
 </div>
```

Hope this helps you !

Comment: your example indeed is working but it doesn't help me because i need to do it from codebehind...updated main post

Comment: Your code should work, when you debug what's the count of items of the DataSource before binding it to repeater?

Comment: on the bebug was everything correct mate..4 items just like intended..found the solution of my problem and updated the code on my topic :-)